# Auto-spacing input field value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a payment form and one of that field is the card number for VISA, Master Card and so on. My question is how to auto space the value (card number) enter by a user.

Let's say I input:

```
4242 4242 4242 4242
```

Comment: I don't have codes for this yet. I really don't know what I'm going to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is an input mask.. you could try this **[Input Mask jQuery](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask)**

```
<input id="creditCard" />

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#creditCard").inputmask("mask", {"mask": "9999 9999 9999 9999"}); //specifying fn & options
});
```

here is a  [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zcmx3/1/)

Comment: Is there any other option? Looks like the jquery.js will give me a problem.

Comment: You could implement it yourself :P in js... whya JQ is a problem ?

Comment: The template buy by my boss has many restrictions. The template have built-in scripts. So if I put other script there and implement it, other functions will no longer be work or it will broke.

Comment: I can only put simple jquery

Comment: I will consider this and try to fix. Thanks